# (Angular) How to return an Observable in my case?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am having trouble to return an observable. My codes and error are below:

```
Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Subscription>'
```

Codes:

```
book.service.ts

import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

export class bookService {
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        ...others
    ) {}

addNewBook(book): Observable<Subscription>{
     ####### tokenService.getToken() outputs the above error. 
    return this.tokenService.getToken().subscribe((token: string) => { 
        const myUrl = "www.testurl.com";
        const parameters = {
            bookTitle: book.name,
        };

        return this.http.post<Book>(myUrl, book);

    })
}
```

token.service.ts

```
public token$: Subject<string>;

..others

public getToken(): Observable<string> {
    return this.token$;
}
```

book.component.ts that calls the addNewBook method.

```
...others
    return Promise.resolve()
         .then(() => {
              return bookService.addNewBook(book).toPromise();         
         }).then((result) => {
             console.log(result); 
         })
```

I can't really change the token service because it's used on other place, I want to turn the observable to promise so I use `toPromise()`. Is there a way to bypass the error? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why is your return type `Observable<Subscription>`. A subscription is just something you dispose when you’re done observing the observable.

Comment: hm. what should I use then?

Comment: If you want the function to execute the request and return nothing, you should return Subscription. If you want the calling code to have the ability to consume the response, you'll need to return an Observable and let the calling code subscribe (and therefore execute the request).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to use Rx **mergeMap** operator and the return type might be wrong (or the type you are passing to post method, I'm gonna assume the return type is wrong but if not you need to also map post method to a valid type):

```
addNewBook(book): Observable<Book> {
    return this.tokenService.getToken().mergeMap((token: string) => { 
        const myUrl = "www.testurl.com";
        const parameters = {
            bookTitle: book.name,
        };

        return this.http.post<Book>(myUrl, book);

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `mergeMap` operator to handle a subscription inside an `observable`.

```
addNewBook(book): Observable<Book>{
    return this.tokenService.getToken().pipe(
      mergeMap((token: string) => {
        const myUrl = "www.testurl.com";
        const parameters = {
            bookTitle: book.name,
        };
        return this.http.post<Book>(myUrl, book);
      })
   )
 }
```

Comment: `pipe` is used to make things easier to read, but here it's just making the method more verbose.

Comment: According to RxJS Version 6 you should definitely use the pipe operator.

Comment: According to who? There's no use for it here.

Comment: `.pipe(mergeMap(...))` means the same thing as `.mergeMap(...)`.

Comment: With RxJS Version 6 and Typescript you can't to `.mergeMap(...)` you get an Type Error, because `mergeMap()` doesn't exist on type `Observable`.

Comment: Interesting. Guess I've been away from js too long.

Comment: Never mind! Things are changing so fast in Javascript/Typescript :)